# get all the columns and rows from this table where the a rwo repeats more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

```
| tableid |      Email |      date |Prymary Record|
|       1 |        x   | 12-DEC-09 | Yes          |  
|       1 |        y   | 12-DEC-09 | No           | 
|       1 |        y   | 13-DEC-09 | No           |
|       2 |        z   | 14-DEC-09 | Yes          |
|       3 |        W   | 14-DEC-09 | Yes          |
|       4 |        W   | 14-DEC-09 | Yes          |
|       4 |        W   | 14-DEC-09 | No           |
```

I want to get all the columns and rows from this table where the tableid repeats more than once

Comment: BTW the downvote was likely because you simply asked for what you want but we have no idea what you tried, what RDBMS it really is, etc. You should have a basic understanding of what you are trying to do and ask for help instead of asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO LOL! Still cracking up on that last comment.

Comment: @logixologist If they don't read the FAQ, why bother explaining how downvotes work? They can just roll their mouse over the down arrow.

Comment: I thought it would be appropriate to be just precise. But will post the efforts and more details from next time, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in SQL Server, you can also do:

```
 select *
 from (
    select *
    , cnt = count(*) over (partition by tableid)
    from mytable
 ) x
 where x.cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one say:

```
select * from mytable
where id in (
    select id from mytable
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1)
```